# How to use tokens from 2 time range inputs in single Splunk dashboard query?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I'm using Splunk classic dashboards where I have 2 time range inputs. I want to compare data for 2 time frames in a single table. Essentially, I want to perform query which counts errors by type for period A and B, then join the searches by error type so that I can see how many errors of each type there were in period A as opposed to period B.

I added a panel as follows:

[image]

because I want to use tokens from both time inputs for the query:

```
(index=myindex) earliest="$runATimeInput.earliest$" latest="$runATimeInput.latest$" environment="$runAEnvironment$"  level=ERROR 
| spath input=message 
| stats count by  logIdentifier 
| sort count desc 
| join left=L right=R where L.logIdentifier = R.logIdentifier 
    [| search (index=myindex) earliest="$runBTimeInput.earliest$" latest="$runBTimeInput.latest$"  environment="$runBEnvironment$"  level=ERROR 
    | spath input=message 
    | stats count by logIdentifier ]
```

The problem is that the query doesn't return any results although it should. The main query returns results:

```
(index=myindex) earliest="$runATimeInput.earliest$" latest="$runATimeInput.latest$" environment="$runAEnvironment$"  level=ERROR 
| spath input=message 
| stats count by logIdentifier 
| sort count desc
```

However the subsearch query doesn't return any results (although a separate search for the same period in a new tab returns results):

```
[| search (index=myindex) earliest="$runBTimeInput.earliest$" latest="$runBTimeInput.latest$"  environment="$runBEnvironment$"  level=ERROR 
| spath input=message 
| stats count by  logIdentifier ]
```

When I click on `Run Search` in Splunk panel in order to open the search in a new tab I see strange values for `earliest`/`latest` tokens. For the main query the values are: `earliest="1669500000" latest="1669506493.677"` where `1669500000` is the `Tue Jan 20 1970 09:45:00` and `1669506493.677` is `Sun Nov 27 2022 01:48:13` whereas the timeframe for period 1 was `Sun Nov 27 2022 00:00:00 - Sun Nov 27 2022 01:48:13`. That being said the main query works and it respects the original time frame.

The values for the second query are `earliest="1669813200" latest="1669816444.909"` where  `1669813200` is `Tue Jan 20 1970 09:45:00` and `1669816444.909` is `Wed Nov 30 2022 15:54:04` whereas the period 2 timeframe was `Wed Nov 30 2022 15:00:04 -` Wed Nov 30 2022 15:54:04`.

Am I doing something wrong in the panel settings or the query? Or maybe there's another way to do this in Splunk?

Below is the dashboard XML:

```xml
<form>
  <label>My Dashboard</label>
  <description>My Dashboard</description>
  <fieldset submitButton="false" autoRun="true">
    <input type="time" token="runATimeInput" searchWhenChanged="true">
      <label>Run A</label>
      <default>
        <earliest>-24h@h</earliest>
        <latest>now</latest>
      </default>
    </input>
    <input type="dropdown" token="runAEnvironment" searchWhenChanged="true">
      <label>Run A Environment</label>
      <choice value="prod">prod</choice>
      <default>prod</default>
    </input>
    <input type="time" token="runBTimeInput" searchWhenChanged="true">
      <label>Run B</label>
      <default>
        <earliest>-24h@h</earliest>
        <latest>now</latest>
      </default>
    </input>
    <input type="dropdown" token="runBEnvironment" searchWhenChanged="true">
      <label>Run B Environment</label>
      <choice value="prod">prod</choice>
      <default>prod</default>
    </input>
  </fieldset>
  <row>
    <panel>
      <title>Top Exceptions</title>
      <table>
        <title>Top Exceptions</title>
        <search>
          <query>(index=distapps) earliest="$runATimeInput.earliest$" latest="$runATimeInput.latest$" environment="$runAEnvironment$"  level=ERROR  | spath input=message 
| stats count by  logIdentifier 
| sort count desc 
| join left=L right=R where L.logIdentifier = R.logIdentifier 
    [| search (index=myindex) earliest="$runBTimeInput.earliest$" latest="$runBTimeInput.latest$"  environment="$runBEnvironment$"  level=ERROR 
    | spath input=message 
    | stats count by logIdentifier ]</query>
          <earliest>$runATimeInput.earliest$</earliest>
          <latest>$runBTimeInput.latest$</latest>
        </search>
        <option name="drilldown">none</option>
        <option name="refresh.display">progressbar</option>
      </table>
    </panel>
  </row>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a test dashboard I created that uses two timepickers.  It produces results for both time periods.  How is yours different?  Could it be the `count` field is used in both the main and subsearches?

```
<form version="1.1">
  <label>test</label>
  <fieldset submitButton="false">
    <input type="time" token="runATimeInput">
      <label>A</label>
      <default>
        <earliest>-24h@h</earliest>
        <latest>now</latest>
      </default>
    </input>
    <input type="time" token="runBTimeInput">
      <label>B</label>
      <default>
        <earliest>-48h@h</earliest>
        <latest>-24h@h</latest>
      </default>
    </input>
  </fieldset>
  <row>
    <panel>
      <table>
        <search>
          <query>(index=_internal) earliest="$runATimeInput.earliest$" latest="$runATimeInput.latest$"
| stats count as countA by component 
| join component [| search (index=_internal) earliest="$runBTimeInput.earliest$" latest="$runBTimeInput.latest$"  
    | stats count as countB by component ]</query>
          <earliest>$runATimeInput.earliest$</earliest>
          <latest>$runATimeInput.latest$</latest>
          <sampleRatio>1</sampleRatio>
        </search>
        <option name="drilldown">none</option>
        <option name="refresh.display">progressbar</option>
      </table>
    </panel>
  </row>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes `count` is used in both main and subsearch. Also I added the dashboard XML to the OP.

Comment: Please try using countA and countB as in my example to see if it helps.

Comment: Having different names for `count` does matter, without it the joined data has just one `count` column.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use any tokens or time selector on the *panel* itself

You should be able to reference your two time tokens' `.earliest` and `.latest` just fine in any searches on the dashboard

Comment: I want to use time inputs to control the timeframe of each period I can't just hardcode `earliest`/`latest` values and I **have** to use some kind of token/time input range in the panel

Comment: Also I have to select some kind of time selector in `Time Range` dropdown in Panel settings

Comment: @hitchhiker - I didn't say don't use a time picker, I said don't reference it on the panel, using the token in your searches (earliest=$timetok1.earliest$, latest=$timetok1.latest$; earliest=$timetok2.earliest$, latest=$timetok2.latest$)

Comment: Can you please specify what should be in the panel settings screenshot as described in the OP? What should be selected in `Time Range` field?

Comment: @hitchhiker - don't select a time range :) just put the tokens into the SPL on the panel

Comment: but something **must** be selected in the Time Range dropdown, I have to select some option.

Comment: @hitchhiker - you don't have to select anything (just whatever the default is is fine). You're going to promptly *ignore* what was chosen there by hardcoding the `earliest=` and `latest=` in your search on the panel :)